# Trying to customize failed login with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Im trying to add more information in the failure login response from Spring Security.

Here is my configuration:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;
    private final CustomAuthEntryPoint customAuthEntryPoint;

    public SecurityConfig(CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider, CustomAuthEntryPoint customAuthEntryPoint) {
        this.authProvider = authProvider;
        this.customAuthEntryPoint = customAuthEntryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors().and()
            .logout().deleteCookies("SESSION").and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()         
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthEntryPoint).and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class CustomAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("entrypoint " + exception.getClass().getName());
        response.getOutputStream().print(exception.getClass().getName());
        response.sendError(401, exception.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

When I try to login, it goes a first time in the custom entry point with the good exception (`BadCredentialsException`) but next I think Spring tries a request to `/error` and then it goes back in the entrypoint with `InsufficientAuthenticationException` (from `ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication` ).

And In the response I have a 401 without any body, even the exception classname as defined in the entrypoint.

Any idea what is wrong with the configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, spring tries to redirect to "/error", because you called  response.sendError in your CustomAuthEntryPoint and tries to authenticate again, thus you get another InsufficentAuthentication exception.
One way to solve this is to use **response.setStatus(401)** instead of the **response.sendError** method. Like so:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("entrypoint " + exception.getClass().getName());
    response.getOutputStream().print(exception.getClass().getName());
    response.setStatus(401);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could exclude "/error" url from authorization, but you have to be careful not to leak sensitive information on that error endpoint:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors().and()
            .logout().deleteCookies("SESSION").and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**","/error").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()         
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthEntryPoint).and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Im gonna use `setStatus` then.